# Terraform How to add Route Rule to an existing route table - Oracle OCI provider

Tags: terraform, oracle-cloud-infrastructure, terraform-provider-oracle

I have an issue that not able to define a set of `route_rules` within `oci_core_default_route_table` resource

```
# VCN Prod Default routing table

resource "oci_core_default_route_table" "default-rt-pub-vcn" {
  manage_default_resource_id = 
  oci_core_vcn.vcn_prod.default_route_table_id
  route_rules = [{
    #Required
    network_entity_id = oci_core_internet_gateway.vcn_prod_IG.id
    #Optional
    destination_type = "CIDR_BLOCK"
    destination = "0.0.0.0/0"
    description = "Defualt route to access Internet"
   },
   {
    #Required
    network_entity_id = oci_core_local_peering_gateway.LPG_prod.id
    #Optional
    destination_type = "CIDR_BLOCK"
    destination = "192.168.100.0/24"
    description = "Route to hub VCN and hub public subnet"
   }]
}
```

on validation

> │ Error: Unsupported argument
> │
> │ on networking.tf line 101, in resource "oci_core_default_route_table" "default-rt-pub-vcn":
> │ 101: route_rules = [{
> │
> │ An argument named "route_rules" is not expected here. Did you mean to define a block of type "route_rules"?

How can I represent multiple route tables within the default VCN route table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the error, it seems you need to edit the code to look like the following:

```
resource "oci_core_route_table" "default-rt-pub-vcn" {
  manage_default_resource_id = oci_core_vcn.vcn_prod.default_route_table_id

  route_rules {
    #Required
    network_entity_id = oci_core_internet_gateway.vcn_prod_IG.id
    #Optional
    destination_type = "CIDR_BLOCK"
    destination      = "0.0.0.0/0"
    description      = "Defualt route to access Internet"
   }

  route_rules {
    #Required
    network_entity_id = oci_core_local_peering_gateway.LPG_prod.id
    #Optional
    destination_type = "CIDR_BLOCK"
    destination      = "192.168.100.0/24"
    description      = "Route to hub VCN and hub public subnet"
 }
}
```

This means that there can be multiple `route_rules` blocks but not an argument (i.e., `route_rules =` ).

Comment: I tested that also, but it didn't work, it passes the configuration validation. but in that case, it will delete the first route and provision the second route, and on the next apply, it will do vice versa delete the second route and provision the first route. ! so both route can't be applied at the same time

Comment: Hm, ok, I don't have a way to test other options since it's Oracle. I'll try something else and let you know so you can maybe test to see if that works.

Comment: @doubando Which provider version are you using? I can't seem to find the `oci_core_default_route_table` resource in the docs for the latest version.

Comment: i'm using the almost the latest hashicorp/oci v4.97.0

Comment: also  resolved the issue by using oci_core_route_table instead of oci_core_default_route_table as the default it could related to a bug, thanks Marko

Comment: Acceptance of the answer would be much appreciated.